# RSolve[{y[0] == y0, y[t + 1] == (1 - (t + 1)/100) y[t]}, y[t], t]

Tags: difference-equations

When I evaluate this code:

```
RSolve[{y[0] == y0, y[t + 1] == (1 - (t + 1)/100) y[t]}, y[t], t]
```

I get an RSolve::bvnul error.  I don't understand why.

Yet, if I run this code, I get the sequence I want.

```
FoldList[#1 (1 - #2) &, 1, Range[1/100, 1, 1/100]]
```

The motivation for this problem is a discrete mortality model in which hazard increases in a linear way until age 100. I'd like a closed form solution for the sequence for an arbitrary maximum life span.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit**

If the corresponding model is to be used for a lifespan `L`, then `RSolve` works:

```
RSolve[{y[0] == y0, y[1 + t] == (1 + 1/L (-1 - t)) y[t]}, y[t], t]
(* {{y[t] -> -(-1 + L) (-L)^-t y0 Pochhammer[2 - L, -1 + t]}} *)
```

I suspect that `RSolve` fails because `1 - (t + 1)/100` becomes zero.  Although mathematically that shouldn't matter, algorithmically it may.

**Original**

Is this not the same thing?

```
Product[(1 - t/100), {t, 1, n}] y0
(* (-(1/100))^n Pochhammer[-99, n] y0 *)

DiscretePlot[(-(1/100))^n Pochhammer[-99, n], {n, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: DiscretePlot]

Check:

```
FoldList[#1 (1 - #2) &, 1, Range[1/100, 1, 1/100]] == 
 Table[(-(1/100))^n Pochhammer[-99, n], {n, 0, 100}]
(* True *)
```

(One can also substitute an arbitrary lifespan `L` for 100 in the `Product`.)

Comment: Case closed.  Thanks!  Kind of strange how the problem works for an arbitrary lifespan L but does not work when puts in a particular value. And, yes, your Product alternative is at least as good as my FoldList.